# C++ Variable Template. This is UB?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I created a simple C++14 variable template that calculates factorials (just for learning). Then I want print the first 12 factorials.

```
template <int n> const int fact = n * fact<n - 1>;
template <> const int fact<0> = 1;
```

If I replace `fact<12>` with `fact<i>` in following snippet, I get an error, because `i` is not constant.

```cpp
int main()
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        std::cout << fact<12> << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But when I change it to this, I get the expected result.

```
int main()
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        std::cout << *(&fact<12> - i) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Is this Undefined Behavior? It's working as expected on GCC 8.3. [Live example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6e044342dd54188)

Comment: Why are you taking the address of fact<12> then subtracting i and dereferencing the resulting pointer?

Comment: It is not clear what your code is supposed to accomplish, or what "of course i have error" actually results in. Please explain in full sentences what you want to do, and what the problem is.

Comment: Are you trying to hack your program with pointer arithmetic to "navigate" independent globals?

Comment: Turn on the optimizer and watch the smurf hit the fan. Example: https://godbolt.org/z/Rs5H3I

Comment: Unless you can somehow prove that there exist `int`s in memory from `&fact<12>-11` to `&fact<12>`, then you should assume that you have UB when you dereference such a "wild" pointer.

Comment: The "working" approach is certainly UB.

Answer (score 3):

It is UB. Your pointer arithmetic "works by chance" (with UB anything can happen).

You might do, instead, for example:

```
template <std::size_t ... Is>
void print_fact(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    for (int res : {fact<Is>...}) {
        std::cout << res << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_fact(std::make_index_sequence<12>());
}
```

Comment: Doing `((std::cout << fact<Is> << std::endl), ...)` inside `print_fact` also works.

Comment: @0x499602D2: Folding expression is C++17, OP tagged C++14.

Comment: @0x499602D2 In C++14 you can use the initializer list hack.